# Bootstrap navbar on mobile not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm making a site for my club in school (Brazil) and I'd like to know how to fix the issue in my site on mobile. The three lines in mobile when pressed don't do anything.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>ClubeDiversidade</title>
</head>
<style>
body {
background-color: orange;
}

</style>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Clube da diversidade</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pagina inicial <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inscrição</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="sobrenatural.html">Sobrenatural</a>
      </li>
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tecnologia</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Outras atividades</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <center>Bem-vindo!!</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical term. What is not working? Which four lines?

Comment: when i press it, it doesnt show the options.

Comment: Which four lines? What is "it"?

Comment: The `<center>` element is obsolete. Don't use that.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 5):

Hi refers to [Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js).

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript plugins. Place the following s near the end of your pages, right before the closing </body> tag, to enable them. jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.

You need to add these lines into your page in order to work.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I used [Bootstrap 4 Editor](http://www.itwonders-web.com/tools/bootstrap4-editor) and copied your code in and it works perfectly, because the editor has built-in bootstrap javascripts.

Comment: This is the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **jquery** and **bootstrap** js before closing the body to get the working toggle.

**Note**: The order is important here, put the jquery js link first and then bootstrap js.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>ClubeDiversidade</title>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    background-color: orange;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Clube da diversidade</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pagina inicial <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inscrição</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="sobrenatural.html">Sobrenatural</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tecnologia</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Outras atividades</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <center>Bem-vindo!!</center>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Remember to put jquery first and then your bootstrap js.