# why navbar is not working in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap navbar. When the screen resizes or when it's opened from mobile, the navbar does not work. It just gets stuck! I have searched for solutions for it and all solutions did not work, like the answers here:

- ["Mobile" Bootstrap-Navbar not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956741/mobile-bootstrap-navbar-not-working/21957318)
- [Bootstrap navbar on mobile not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515462/bootstrap-navbar-on-mobile-not-working)

image result:
[1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uhVIO5o8axQ5EiR08HjpZ8nlZU-RZG3j/view?usp=sharing
The problem is that the menu on the right is not opening or closing, but in bigger screens its working

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 200) {
      $('.navbar').addClass('fixed-top');
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('fixed-top');
    }
  });

  function adjustNav() {
    var winWidth = $(window).width(),
      dropdown = $('.dropdown'),
      dropdownMenu = $('.dropdown-menu');

    if (winWidth >= 768) {
      dropdown.on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).addClass('show')
          .children(dropdownMenu).addClass('show');
      });

      dropdown.on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('show')
          .children(dropdownMenu).removeClass('show');
      });
    } else {
      dropdown.off('mouseenter mouseleave');
    }
  }

  $(window).on('resize', adjustNav);

  adjustNav();
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster');
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.button-primary {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #c0ca33;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: color 0.3s ease-in;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button-primary:hover {
  color: #c0ca33;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button-primary::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.8);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0.8);
  transform: scaleX(0.8);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  z-index: -1;
}

.button-primary:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.overlay::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.header-area {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #5bc0de;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repear;
  background-size: cover;
}

.banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.banner h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.banner p {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: background 0.6s ease-in;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler .menu-icon-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-1px);
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler .menu-icon-bar:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1px) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-sform: translateY(-1px) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(-1px) rotate(45deg);
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler .menu-icon-bar:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1px) rotate(135deg);
  -ms-sform: translateY(-1px) rotate(135deg);
  transform: translateY(-1px) rotate(135deg);
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler.collapsed .menu-icon-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler.collapsed .menu-icon-bar:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(0);
  -ms-sform: translateY(-7px) rotate(0);
  transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(0);
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler.collapsed .menu-icon-bar:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(5px) rotate(0);
  -ms-sform: translateY(5px) rotate(0);
  transform: translateY(5px) rotate(0);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #c0ca33;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #c0ca33;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-animation: navbar-animation 0.6s;
  animation: navbar-animation 0.6s;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.navbar.fixed-top.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: #c0ca33;
}

.navbar.fixed-top.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link::after {
  background-color: #c0ca33;
}

.content {
  padding: 120px 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  }
  .navbar.fixed-top .navbar-nav {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .banner {
    padding: 0 150px;
  }
  .banner h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
  .banner p {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding: 23px 15px;
  }
  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
  }
  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover::after {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: dropdown-animation 0.3s;
    animation: dropdown-animation 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes navbar-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes navbar-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dropdown-animation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    transform: scaleY(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@keyframes dropdown-animation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    transform: scaleY(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./nstyle.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <header class="header-area overlay">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Tiara</a>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
                <span class="menu-icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="menu-icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="menu-icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 2</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 3</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 2</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 3</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 4</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 5</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="banner">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Bootstrap 4 Navbar</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec elit ex. Etiam elementum lectus et tempor molestie.</p>
        <a href="#content" class="button button-primary">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js'></script>
  <script src="./nscript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where are you loading Bootstrap's JavaScript file? Is it in your nscript.js file?

Comment: yes ... and the javascript code is mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

There may be something in your nscript.js file (which isn’t in the snippet) that’s causing problems. If I copy your code into a separate snippet, it seems to work. I'm not sure what you mean by "stuck", but in the snippet below, the menu will open and close.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 200) {
      $('.navbar').addClass('fixed-top');
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('fixed-top');
    }
  });

  function adjustNav() {
    var winWidth = $(window).width(),
      dropdown = $('.dropdown'),
      dropdownMenu = $('.dropdown-menu');

    if (winWidth >= 768) {
      dropdown.on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).addClass('show')
          .children(dropdownMenu).addClass('show');
      });

      dropdown.on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('show')
          .children(dropdownMenu).removeClass('show');
      });
    } else {
      dropdown.off('mouseenter mouseleave');
    }
  }

  $(window).on('resize', adjustNav);

  adjustNav();
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster');

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.button-primary {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #c0ca33;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: color 0.3s ease-in;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button-primary:hover {
  color: #c0ca33;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button-primary::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.8);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0.8);
  transform: scaleX(0.8);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  z-index: -1;
}

.button-primary:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.overlay::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.header-area {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #5bc0de;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repear;
  background-size: cover;
}

.banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.banner h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.banner p {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: background 0.6s ease-in;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler .menu-icon-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-1px);
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler .menu-icon-bar:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1px) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-sform: translateY(-1px) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(-1px) rotate(45deg);
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler .menu-icon-bar:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1px) rotate(135deg);
  -ms-sform: translateY(-1px) rotate(135deg);
  transform: translateY(-1px) rotate(135deg);
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler.collapsed .menu-icon-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler.collapsed .menu-icon-bar:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(0);
  -ms-sform: translateY(-7px) rotate(0);
  transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(0);
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler.collapsed .menu-icon-bar:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(5px) rotate(0);
  -ms-sform: translateY(5px) rotate(0);
  transform: translateY(5px) rotate(0);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #c0ca33;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #c0ca33;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-animation: navbar-animation 0.6s;
  animation: navbar-animation 0.6s;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.navbar.fixed-top.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: #c0ca33;
}

.navbar.fixed-top.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link::after {
  background-color: #c0ca33;
}

.content {
  padding: 120px 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

  .navbar-nav {
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  }

  .navbar.fixed-top .navbar-nav {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .banner {
    padding: 0 150px;
  }

  .banner h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }

  .banner p {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding: 23px 15px;
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
  }

  .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover::after {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

  .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: dropdown-animation 0.3s;
    animation: dropdown-animation 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes navbar-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes navbar-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dropdown-animation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    transform: scaleY(1.1);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@keyframes dropdown-animation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.1);
    transform: scaleY(1.1);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <header class="header-area overlay">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Tiara</a>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
                <span class="menu-icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="menu-icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="menu-icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 2</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 3</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 2</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 3</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 4</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item 5</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="banner">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Bootstrap 4 Navbar</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec elit ex. Etiam elementum lectus et tempor molestie.</p>
        <a href="#content" class="button button-primary">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: I have provided an image result for the run, after resizing it suppose thats the size of mobile view then the menu you see on your right is not opening or closing thats the problem and the code in the snipppet is the same in my nscript.js file

Comment: I looked again at your snippet using the developer tools and there’s no event handler getting attached to the `navabar toggler` (the event handler that opens the menu comes from the Bootstrap JavaScript file), but an event handler is getting attached in my snippet. Your additional image shows the same page as my snippet. Just to confirm, when you click the menu button on yours, nothing happens, but if you run my code snippet (on a small screen), the menu is showing, right? The only difference between the snippets is mine has the Bootstrap JS file specifically included.

Comment: @RichDeBourke You seem to be right. The line `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>` is missing in the head of the HTML originally posted. The script only includes jquery.